# How to find WPS Spreadsheet exe, located in wine (lubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, wine, executable

I have installed wine-staging from [this site](https://wine-staging.com/installation.html) in my lubuntu 16.04 box , and also installed WPS 2016 (setup.exe) in wine.

So after installing WPS successfully ,i am trying to run WPS spreadsheet from wine using command line but i am not able to find its executable file i,e .exe for spreadsheet.

For example i have also install MS office 2007 in wine & executable for MS office(2007) Excel file is located at

```
/home/wineuser/.wineprefix/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/EXCEL.EXE
```

And it can run using below command from terminal :

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.testadmin WINE=/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine ~/.testadmin/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/EXCEL.EXE
```

So my question is how can i run WPS spreadsheet under wine in lubuntu box 16.04 , where its executable actually located ?

Comment: Why are you using WPS in Wine? You can use WPS natively in Linux.

Comment: http://wps-community.org/download.html

Comment: Yes i know but i am using it in wine for some testing purpose.

Comment: Browse "drive_c" and you should find it.

Comment: @MichaelBay  I have crosschecked in this /home/admin/.admin/drive_c/users/admin/Local Settings/Application Data/Kingsoft/WPS Office/* but not able to find any .exe file i,e  spreadsheet , writer & presentation.

Comment: Looking for the executable in the settings folder makes no sense. It should be in the exact folder WPS is installed in Windows, "Program Files" or something, just like you did for MS Office.

Comment: Yes this was my 1st step to check but there is no WPS folder in "drive_c/Program Files/",  as there is MS office "drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/". 

this is list of  "drive_c/Program Files/" 

Common Files  Internet Explorer  Microsoft Office  Microsoft Visual Studio  Microsoft Works  MSBuild  Tally.ERP9  Windows Media Player  Windows NT

Comment: This is really a Windows question. Finding the installation location of a Windows program inside a known Wine prefix has only circumstantial relations to Ubuntu. Are you at least sure of the wine prefix location that you used during installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

When i have install **wps_setup.exe** in wine at that time , the setup had ask me to where to install WPS , by default i go with next next details and clicked install now , so by default setup installed in

`"C:\users\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Kingsoft\WPS Office\"`

but again when i  run **wps_setup.exe** from wine and choose  installation path to

`"C:\Program Files\WPS Office\"` which was correct way.

So the setup install correctly & also i have figured out exe's

for spreadsheet its name **et.exe**   at

`~/.mywineprefix/drive_c/Program\ Files/WPS\ Office/10.2.0.5820/office6/et.exe`

for word its name is **wps.exe** at

```
  ~/.mywineprefix/drive_c/Program\ Files/WPS\ Office/10.2.0.5820/office6/wps.exe
```

for presentation its name is **wpp.exe** at

```
~/.mywineprefix/drive_c/Program\ Files/WPS\ Office/10.2.0.5820/office6/wpp.exe
```

where 10.2.0.5820 is WPS version.

After this i am able to run WPS spreadsheet in wine using command

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.mywineprefix WINE=/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine ~/.mywineprefix/drive_c/Program\ Files/WPS\ Office/10.2.0.5820/office6/et.exe
```

Comment: and there is **wpspdf** to view PDFs. Thats the linux binary. Windows equivalent is probably wpspdf.exe